# Retrieving values of collection from multiple classes, what's the correct way?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, global-variables

Before anything, thanks for reading!

I'm developing an application in C++ and I want an advice about a design issue. Let me explain:

The main class of my application has some collections, but other classes eventually need to get a value from one of those collections. Something like this:

```
class MainClass { 
private:
   // Collections are internally implemented as QHash
   Collection<Type1> col1;
   Collection<Type2> col2;
};
class RosterUnit {
public:
   RosterUnit() {
      /* This method needs to get a specific value from col1 and
         initialize this class with that data */
   }
};

class ObjectAction {
public:
    virtual void doAction() = 0;
};

class Action1 : public ObjectAction {
public:
    void doAction() {
       // This needs a specific value from col2
    }
};

class Action2 : public ObjectAction {
public:
    void doAction() {
       // This needs a specific value from col1
    }
};
```

My first approach was passing the whole collection as parameter when needed, but it is not so good for ObjectAction subclasses, because I would have to pass the two collections and if I later create another subclass of ObjectAction and it needs to get an element from other collection (suppose col3), I would have to modify the doAction() signature of every ObjectAction subclass, and I think that is not too flexible. Also, suppose I have a Dialog and want to create a RosterUnit from there. I would have to pass the collection to the dialog just to create the RosterUnit.

Next I decided to use static variables in RosterUnit and ObjectAction that pointed to the collections, but I'm not very happy with that solution. I think it is not flexible enough.

I have been reading about design patterns and I first thought a Singleton with get functions could be a good choice, but after some more investigation I think it isn't a proper design for my case. It would be easier and more or less the same if I use global variables, which don't seem to be the right way.

So, could you give some advices, please?

Thank you very much!

Comment: @amit - OMG!  Just because the word "singleton" appears in a question doesn't make it a duplicate of the one you said it is!!!  Did you even bother reading the question??  This question has barely anything to do with singletons except in passing mention.

Comment: Daniel - design is a very particular kind of thing; what's great in one case is horrible in another.  Without really knowing the domain you're working in, and especially what "MainClass" is supposed to represent, it's pretty much impossible to give good design advise.  My initial leaning is that you're going down a dark alley, as your description sounds really confusing, but I simply don't know enough about what you're doing to be any help.

Comment: Like trying to close someone's question you didn't even read is "polite".

Comment: @amit - well, I'd suggest that you learn the difference between "duplicate" and "vaguely covers some of the same material".  Calling something a duplicate and trying to close it as such should be reserved for questions that cover ALL of the same material, not a case like this when one, small aspect of a question is somewhat answered by another.

Comment: @CrazyEddie: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough. Sometimes it is a bit hard to explain a problem without givin many details so the post isn't too long.. MainClass is right now the MainWindow (I'm using Qt, so it is a class which inherits QMainWindow). It basically has the UI elements of the main window and related methods. Basically I want to know how should I let external classes get one element of those collections without having to pass references in each method, or just the best way.

Thank you!

Comment: @amit: it is hardly polite to vote to close a question for an invalid reason either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned previously, Iterators are good for abstracting away the details of the Collection. But going this route implies that the objects that use the Iterators will need to know about what's inside the Collection. Meaning they will need to know how to decide which object in the Collection they need, thus increasing the coupling. (more details below in the Factory paragraph) This is something you need to consider.

Another approach would be to create accessor methods on the MainClass that take some sort of key and return an object from the Collection (findObject(key)). Internally the MainClass methods would search through the container(s) and return the appropriate object. To use this approach, you will however need access to the MainClass, either by dependancy injection as mentioned before, or possibly making it a Singleton (not recomended in this scenario, though).

With the info provided so far, it may even be better for your ObjectAction Factory to have a reference to the MainClass, and as a part of the ObjectAction creation logic, call the appropriate MainClass accessor and pass the result into the ObjectAction, thus decoupling the ObjectAction Objects from the MainClass.

Comment: The MainClass approach sounds good, but I would need to have it as a global, and I don't know how good it is.
I couldn't use the appropiate MainClass accessor when I initialize the ObjectAction because the data could not be available in that moment.

I create the proper ObjectAction with data from a file, and from the same file (XML), I read the collection elements. So, if the ObjectAction is created before the element data is read, it would end in an invalid state.

Comment: How about extending the ObjectAction Factory, so in addition to creating ObjectAction Objects, it serves as a getter for the MainClass Collection accessors? That way the Factory would have the reference to the MainClass and it wouldnt have to be global.

Comment: So I would have to have the same for RosterUnit, right? Right now I'm doing something like that, which seems to be the best choice..

Comment: I dont completely understand the relation between the RosterUnit class and the ObjectAction classes, so its hard to answer. Either way, I would try to avoid Globals at all costs!

Comment: They aren't directly related. They just need an element from a specific collection!
Right now I'm not using globals. I'm just sharing a reference with two or three classes. Is it right?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use iterators, they exist exactly for the purpose of abstracting away sequences from specific containers.

If your issue is how to pass the iterators to the code that needs them in the first place, do not give in to the temptation to use globals. It may look more convoluted if you have to pass parameters in, but your code is that much more decoupled for it. "Dependency Injection" is a good keyword if you want to read more about this topic.

I would also advise you to check out std::function or boost::function instead of inheriting from ObjectAction. Functional style is getting more common in modern C++, as opposed to how it's usually done in languages like Java.

Comment: I don't think I should use iterators as I only need one element per time. e.g: In the RosterUnit constructor, I only need one base element (which is part of one collection) to initialize the class.

My issue is basically what you are saying in the second paragraph. Just I don't want to pass the collections to classes that don't directly need them. e.g: What if I have a dialog from which I create a RosterUnit? I'd have to pass the collections to the dialog just to create the instance.

I will search Dependency Injection.

What advantages provides std::function over the polymorphic way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough information here of what you are trying to do. You make it sound like 'at some point in the future, this statically created action needs this data that was left behind.' How does that make any sense? I would say either construct the actions *with the data*, as you would for instance with a Future or Callable), or have the command ask for the next piece of data, in which case you are just implementing a Work queue.

Sounds like you are trying to do something like a thread pool. If these actions are in any way related, then you should have then in some composing object, implementing something like the **Template Method** pattern, e.g. execute() is abstract and calls a few other methods in a fixed sequence and that cannot be overridden, the other methods must be (protocol enforcement).

Comment: What I meant is a particular ObjectAction subclass may, for example, create a new RosterUnit instance (so it will need access to one element of one Collection). I use the Factory Method pattern to create an ObjectAction, and there I don't have access to the collections, so probably it does not work.

The ObjectAction::doAction() does not enforce anything. It just recieves the RosterUnit where it should perform the action, but what it does is limited only by the RosterUnit public interface. So I think Template Method is not good here.

Comment: So the collection is what? That should be a sign to you that your model has holes in it. What it sounds like is 'I am keeping this classless bag of state sitting around so I can make things from it later.' There is no design pattern that is going to fix that. You can't get a good solution to a modeling problem if the model is not clear.

Comment: Collection is just a QHash. I fill the data in the main class. A particular subclass of ObjectAction creates an instance of RosterUnit. So I want to find a correct way to let that subclass create that instance. Right now I just share a const reference to the collection with the RosterUnit class, so it gets the element in its constructor directly (so you don't need to pass the element as parameter). Is it the correct way? 

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, Dude, still not enough information. You have some data that is stuffed into the main class that is then used to create instances of this RosterUnit class? You could consider a Prototype pattern.

Comment: Here's how prototype would work. Suppose you have a team that has a different Roster for home than for away. You could setup a class called RosterPrototype, with 2 instances in the base class. Then when you want to create a new roster, you would call, for instance, awayRosterPrototype.newInstance(). The idea behind prototype is that new instances have some initial state when they are created.

Comment: It sounds interesting, but what about the ObjectAction subclasses? In one I need to add a new RosterUnit, so I would have to share the "away" RosterPrototype.